# Cutting an animated GIF file on Windows

Tags: windows, gif

I am looking for a GUI program that can cut an animated  GIF file.

E.g. if the GIF file has a length of 20 seconds, I would like to be able to create a new GIF file that would correspond to the old one from second 5 to 15.

Free, lightweight and portable would be ideal.

I believe [Adobe ImageReady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ImageReady) used to be able to do it but the program was discontinued (last release: 2005).

---

Here is an animated GIF file:

[image: animated gif file]

**Note**: Back in Windows 2k or 95 I believe I had a very simple program to remove/add frames in a gif file. But I forgot the name ... and I'm more into Windows 7 nowadays.

Comment: Not sure about *editing* – but I know Gimp can be used to create such GIFs, so I'd be surprised if it couldn't edit them. Well, not lightweight – but portable and free. Acceptable? You say (after having verified it works – I have no animated GIF at hand to try).

Comment: @Izzy thanks, yes that would work, I just need to find out a way to [delete several frames from an animated GIF file at once in GIMP](http://superuser.com/q/1010832/116475).

Comment: *LOL* At GraphicsDesign.SE they do that with a simple Bash script: [How to remove every second frame from an animated gif?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20908/how-to-remove-every-second-frame-from-an-animated-gif) The [AnimStack Gimp plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/26501) seems to have such a feature as well.

Comment: @Izzy :) back in Windows 2k or 95 I believe I had a very simple program to remove/add frames in a gif file. But I forgot the name... and I'm more into Windows 7 nowadays.

Comment: another vote for GIMP, although it does have a steep learning curve, it is very powerful. heres my suggestion for another question regarding GIFs without any love XD http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/app-to-remove-duplicate-frames-in-an-animated-gif/26963#26963

Answer (score 4):

#### [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/)

- Free and [open source](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif)
- No install
- actually works!
- Has a mutipal modes: Recorder, Webcam, Board and Editor (you are interested only in the editor)

It is quite easy to cut a gif. Launch the Editor, open the gif.
In the frame scrubber at the bottom, select the frames you want to delete, press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Then *Save as Gif*. Bonus is that the file size it generates is quite good.